# Basic T-SQL to compare two same length strings

Tags: strings, sql, sql-server, t-sql, edit-distance

I've come up with the following T-SQL to compare similar same length strings.

Example usage would be:

- OCR returns a value which is expected to be in the database.
- PATINDEX is used to check the value's in the database, including matching for common errors (e.g. 0/O, I/1/l).
- If multiple values are found, each match is scored for likeness to the original.

```
declare @t table (solution nvarchar(32), score bigint)

insert @t(solution) 
select 'Portugal'
union select '9ortugal'
union select '9ortu8al'
union select 'Portu8al'
union select 'P0rtugal'
union select '90rtugal'
union select '90rtu8al'
union select 'P0rtu8al'
union select 'Portuga1'
union select '9ortuga1'
union select '9ortu8a1'
union select 'Portu8a1'
union select 'P0rtuga1'
union select '90rtuga1'
union select '90rtu8a1'
union select 'P0rtu8a1'

declare @answer nvarchar(32) = 'Portugal'

update @t 
set score = cast(cast(cast(@answer as varchar) as varbinary(max)) as bigint) - (cast(cast(cast(solution as varchar) as varbinary(max)) as bigint) & cast(cast(cast(@answer as varchar) as varbinary(max)) as bigint))

select * from @t order by score --first result is the most similar
```

Results:

> ```
> solution    score
> Portugal    0
> Portuga1    76
> Portu8al    4653056
> Portu8a1    4653132
> P0rtugal    22236523160141824
> P0rtuga1    22236523160141900
> P0rtu8al    22236523164794880
> P0rtu8a1    22236523164794956
> 9ortugal    4611686018427387904
> 9ortuga1    4611686018427387980
> 9ortu8al    4611686018432040960
> 9ortu8a1    4611686018432041036
> 90rtugal    4633922541587529728
> 90rtuga1    4633922541587529804
> 90rtu8al    4633922541592182784
> 90rtu8a1    4633922541592182860
> ```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/21230)

Notes:

- Conversion to varchar because nvarchar seems to cause a loss of precision
- Conversion to varbinary because doing varchar straight to numeric would result in a non-numeric issue for non-numeric characters.
- Conversion to bigint to allow bitwise & arithmetic comparison
- Use of - and & may be superfluous; perhaps just the `-` would be sufficient, but I feel (superstitious guess/don't have a strong enough understanding) that the `&` will help.

Concerns:

- Errors at the start of the string have more impact than those later in the string.
- Results look quite good on my test data, but not sure how predictable this would be in reality.
- It would be nice to be able to weight the errors; e.g. O for 0 is very common; 6 for G or 8 for g less so; so the former should have a greater weighting (i.e. P0rtugal should be preferential to Portu8al; not just because of the character's position in the string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you creating your own string similarity algorithm? You realise that casting to `bigint` means that only the first eight bytes are ever used? (first eight characters for `varchar` and first four for `nvarchar` in most collations)?

And the characteristics are heavily dependant on the ASCII codes of the characters?

This leads to some fairly odd (and asymmetrical) results.

```
insert @t(solution) 
SELECT 'cat'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'dog'

DECLARE @answer NVARCHAR(32) = 'Cat'
```

Returns

```
+----------+--------+
| solution | score  |
+----------+--------+
| cat      |      0 |
| dog      | 196624 |
+----------+--------+
```

which looks good so far. Searching for "Cat" matched "cat" with a perfect score.

But reverse the search to look for "cat" with an entry for "Cat" in the data...

```
insert @t(solution) 
SELECT 'Cat'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'dog'

DECLARE @answer NVARCHAR(32) = 'cat'
```

Returns

```
+----------+---------+
| solution |  score  |
+----------+---------+
| dog      |  196624 |
| Cat      | 2097152 |
+----------+---------+
```

I suggest using a tried and tested string similarity algorithm such as [Levenshtein distance](http://levenshtein.blogspot.co.uk/) - possibly implemented as a CLR function.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, a stylistic point. SQL is typically written with keywords capitalised, `SELECT` instead of `select` for example.

Your table and variable names could use a little more meaning. Using `@Countries` or `@CountryNames` in place of the meaningless `@t`, for example.

You use `NVARCHAR` to hold your data, but immediately convert it to `VARCHAR`. I would recommend just using `VARCHAR` in your query, this allows you to remove the cast to `VARCHAR`'s.

Lastly, the logic you use to set the score is a little convoluted, as you thought it might be. I would recommend using:

```sql
SET score = CAST(CAST(@SelectedCountry AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS INT) - CAST(CAST(solution AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS INT)
```

These changes would result in this:

```sql
DECLARE @CoutryNames TABLE (solution VARCHAR(32), score BIGINT)

INSERT INTO @CoutryNames(solution) 
SELECT 'Portugal'
UNION SELECT '9ortugal'
UNION SELECT '9ortu8al'
UNION SELECT 'Portu8al'
UNION SELECT 'P0rtugal'
UNION SELECT '90rtugal'
UNION SELECT '90rtu8al'
UNION SELECT 'P0rtu8al'
UNION SELECT 'Portuga1'
UNION SELECT '9ortuga1'
UNION SELECT '9ortu8a1'
UNION SELECT 'Portu8a1'
UNION SELECT 'P0rtuga1'
UNION SELECT '90rtuga1'
UNION SELECT '90rtu8a1'
UNION SELECT 'P0rtu8a1'

DECLARE @SelectedCountry VARCHAR(32) = 'Portugal'

UPDATE @CoutryNames 
SET score = 
CAST(CAST(@SelectedCountry AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS BIGINT) 
- CAST(CAST(solution AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS BIGINT)

SELECT * FROM @CoutryNames ORDER BY score --first result is the most similar
```

[Here is the SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/21262)

---

The idea to use weighted errors got me thinking about how I would do it.

Here is what I came up with, you could pretty easily turn it into a function by adding the required boilerplate code and changing the `SELECT @ErrorScore` to `RETURN @ErrorScore`:

```sql
DECLARE @StringA VARCHAR(10) = 'bacon',
        @StringB VARCHAR(10) = 'bacon',
        @CharPosition TINYINT = 1,
        @ErrorScore INT = 0

DECLARE @LETTER_WEIGHTING TABLE(CorrectLetter CHAR(1), IncorrectLetter CHAR(1),LetterWeighting TINYINT)

INSERT INTO @LETTER_WEIGHTING
SELECT 'o','0',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'o','Q',3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'g','6',2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'g','8',3

IF @StringA <> @StringB 
BEGIN
    WHILE @CharPosition <= LEN(@StringA)
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
        @ErrorScore +=
        CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@StringA,@CharPosition,1) <> SUBSTRING(@StringB,@CharPosition,1)
        THEN 
        ISNULL((
            SELECT TOP 1 LetterWeighting
            FROM @LETTER_WEIGHTING 
            WHERE CorrectLetter = SUBSTRING(@StringA,@CharPosition,1) 
            AND IncorrectLetter = SUBSTRING(@StringB,@CharPosition,1)
        ),5)
        *
        @CharPosition
        ELSE 0
        END

        SET @CharPosition+=1
    END
END

SELECT @ErrorScore
```

What this does is loop through all the characters of the first string and compare them with the appropriate character in the second string. If the characters do not match, then we use a lookup table of weightings for some errors or we use 5 as a base value if the correct/incorrect character pair is not in the lookup table. We then multiply the value in the previous step by the characters position in the string.

[Here is an SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/38614)

Answer (score 1):

Levenshtein distance algorithm may be used to determine the "distance" between two strings.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560709/levenshtein-distance-in-t-sql